# C++ 0x Lambda parameter in nested template function

Tags: c++, lambda, binary-tree

I am trying to write a generic tree traversal function that takes in a templated BinaryTreeNode and a lambda. I'm not sure why when I use it, the compiler keeps saying it can't find the function ... here's some code:

```
template<typename T>
struct BinaryTreeNode
{
    T Data;
    struct BinaryTreeNode* Parent;
    struct BinaryTreeNode* Left;
    struct BinaryTreeNode* Right;
};

template<typename T, typename Func>
void IterateInOrder(struct BinaryTreeNode<T>* root, Func VisitorFunction)
{
    typename std::stack< struct BinaryTreeNode<T>* > node_stack;
    struct BinaryTreeNode<T>* current = root;

    while(true)
    {
        if(current != nullptr)
        {
            node_stack.push(current);
            current = current->Left;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!node_stack.empty())
            {
                current = node_stack.top();
                VisitorFunction(current);
                node_stack.pop();
                current = current->Right;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

BinaryTreeNode<int> test_tree;
test_tree.Data = 100;
test_tree.Parent = nullptr;
test_tree.Left = nullptr;
test_tree.Right = nullptr;
auto PrintNode = [](struct BinaryTreeNode<int>* node)
{
    printf("%d", node->Data);
};

IterateInOrder(test_tree, PrintNode);   //won't compile. "No matching function..."
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: test_tree is not a pointer.

Comment: `&test_tree` would be a better choice for first param. I don't know what compiler you're using, but clang is pretty explicit about the reason the sig doesn't match: "Candidate template ignored: could not match 'struct BinaryTreeNode<T> *' against 'BinaryTreeNode<int>'"

Comment: I don't think you need to specify `struct` before every `BinaryTreeNode` in modern C++

Comment: wow ... that's true! Now it won't compiled on the push call ... I'm guessing it doesn't like how the node_stack is declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
void IterateInOrder(struct BinaryTreeNode<T>* root, Func VisitorFunction);
```

expects a pointer as first argument, but you pass an instance of `BinaryTreeNode<int>`.

You may use

```
IterateInOrder(&test_tree, PrintNode);
```

Comment: Thank you :( ... now I feel silly ... but now it doesn't like the push method in the IterateInOrder function ...